# Boolean serialization and case-sensitive REST API's

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I'm confronted with a case-sensitive REST API (Pingdom). Python's `urllib` serializes all boolean values to "True" or "False". The API however, only accepts lowercase "true" and "false", as is consistent with the JSON output.

How to cope with this? Should I pre-serialize all bools before feeding them to `requests` or is there a cleaner way?

```
def _serializeBooleans(params):
    for k, v in params.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, bool):
            params[k] = str(v).lower()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless `params` is large, return a modified copy, rather than mutating the inputs, just in case other parts of the code using the same `params` object require real `bool`s.

Don't rely on `str(v)` returning the specific strings. Putting the explicitly in the code also documents that your require those specific strings.

```
def prepare_params(params):
    prepared = {}
    for name, value in params.iteritems():
        if value is True:
            value = 'true'
        elif value is False:
            value = 'false'
        prepared[name] = value
    return prepared
```